# How to disable a Zend_Form_Element_Radio but still include its value in a POST request?

Tags: zend-framework, radio-button, zend-form, readonly

Greetings fellow coders.

In my application I have Zend_Forms with several Zend_Form_Elements. Based on the user' role  I'd like to change some of these elements to a readonly/disabled status. However, it is important that submitting the form still works. POST should send a value for each element. 
So setting the readonly attribute works fine, but disabled does not. If you disable a HTML form element, it does not pass its value in the POST request.

The problem is, that it is not possible to set the readonly attribute on all types of form elements. It has no effect on radio buttons.

```
 /**
 *
 * changes the Zend_Form_Element to a 'readonly' like state
 * 
 * @param String $name (zend-) name of the element
 */
public function readonlyElement($name){
    $elem = $this->getForm()->getElement($name);
    /* @var $elem Zend_Form_Element */

    $attribs = $elem->getAttribs();

    if(is_a($elem, 'Zend_Form_Element_Radio')){
        // !! this does NOT work !!
        $attribs['disabled'] = true;
        $value = $elem->getValue();
        $hidden = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden($name);          
        $hidden->setValue($value);
        $this->getForm()->addElement($hidden);
    }
    else {
        $attribs['readonly'] = true;
    }          

    $style = $attribs['style'];


    $attribs['style'] = $style;
    $elem->setAttribs($attribs);
}
```

I tried to disable the radio button and add a hidden field with the same value and the same name. This did not work, because Zend_Form_Element names have to be unique. I also played around with $elem->setName(), to change the name of the existing element to something else. So far, I was not successful. Do you have any ideas how to solve my problem?

Thanks,

Andreas

To clarify:
This is how I use my forms in a controller:

```
$form = new Some_Form();
//attach filters, validators, remove unneeded elements based on active user
$this->modifyForm($form);
if ($this->getRequest->save){
    if $form->isValid(($this->getRequest->params){
    //...  Check and save
    }
}
else{
    $form->populate($model->toArray());
}
```

'Disabled' fields will be populated first, but if form validation fails they will be empty because no POST data was send. Adding a hidden field with the same name as the disabled field would solve this problem in pure PHP/HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Always validate Values inside of your Model! **Do not rely on your Form-Values alone!** It is a piece of cake for anyone with a modern Browser to change the value of a readonly input.

SO basically do something like this inside your Model

```
switch ($user->getRight()) {
  case 'admin':
    $myCustomField = $this->_getParam('value');
  break;
  case 'normaluser':
    $myCustomField = in_array($this->_getParam('value'), array(
      'values', 'user', 'is', 
      'allowed', 'to', 'set')) ? $this->_getParam('value') : $defaultValue;
  break;
}

$model->setField($myCustomField);
```

Under no circumstances you should rely on anything the form sends. Obviously when using `_getParam('value')` like this there should be some sort of validator checking if the sent id (i guess that's what you're choosing form your radio element) exists in the database (Db_RecordExists)

Comment: I do not agree with you, if you set up validators and filters in your form fields and you use $form->getValidValues() to retrieve your posted data it's safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not relying on my form values for final validation. But I use $form->isValid($this->getRequest->getPost()) in my controllers to validate forms. In case of errors the errors are displayed and all old 'POSTed' values are displayed. (No need to populate() the form again) Therefore if the values of the radio buttons are not send, they will just become uncheck.

Comment: @Kees Schepers I guess Sam was saying don't rely on the form's readonly attribute to ensure that values are not changed.

Comment: @ACNB Well that's why i am saying: If you do not want a user to fill out something, then simply do not show him that particular Form-Element and assign it a default value from your model. // Edit: Posted this answer way after writing it, yes that's exactly what i implied ;)